# testcafe/node.js Error thrown in element query

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

I have the following code snippet in a testcafe script I am writting.

```
32: let NNT = Selector('#notNow').withText('No thanks, not at this time.')
33: button = Selector('.myclass')
34: let email = Vladimir.Putin@gmail.com
35: await t.click(button)
36: let emailS= Selector('#login-email')
37: await t.expect(emailS.visible).ok()
38: await t.debug()
39: await t.typeText(emailS,email)
```

But on line 38 i am getting the following error

Error on page "https://mywebpage.com":

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

I realize this error means that the page my no longer exist however there definitly is a email box here is the html

```
<li>
<label for="login-email">Email Address</label>
<div class="input-box">
<input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="login-email" name="login[username]" value="">
</div>
</li>
```

So in this context what does this error mean.  Thanks in advance.

Update: Upon deleting lines to see where the error is occurring I found the error is thrown immediately after it loads the page containing .myclass is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

where is this property 'top' being referenced?
In this context it means that whatever object you are expecting the property 'top' to exist in, that object does not exist and therefore it is undefined

Comment: but Selector('#login-email') does exist on the page I am on i think at least i have id="login-email"

Comment: the error you're saying you are having doesn't say anything about the selector not existing. Based on the information you are giving me I'd say there is something else going wrong here, not the selector.  Try writing a console.log(emailS.visible) right after line 36, what error do you get?

Comment: the browser dies before then immediately after the 36 for some reason the js is complaining at 38.

Comment: wait, are you saying that the browser dies on line 36?

Comment: what is the button1 that is being clicked on line 35?

Comment: Some class, I watch it click the `button` the page loads then it throws the error without executing the next line

Comment: your test fails because the page crashes. I don't understand what the real problem here is. If the page breaks and your test is waiting for something from that page.

Comment: I just saw that you edited line 35, was that the cause of the problem? Clicking on a button that doesn't exist?

Comment: your correct there is something wrong with the page

Answer (score 2):

This was the problem the web site had some bad references that were not affecting the site but still testcafe was failing because of them.  I ran it with the flag -e.  Then the code works.

Comment: nice, glad to know you have found the solution